# Since the Listview.builder widget in flutter requires a height, some fixed heights I give to the container wrapping the widget causes to overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-design, flutter-container

### Code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Search Families'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: StaticEntry.backColor,
        body: Center(
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.8,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SearchInput(onSubmitHandler: onSubmit),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                ),
                resultList.isNotEmpty
                    ? Container(                    // <---------------- Container that I am using to wrap the list view widget
                        height: 400,                // <---------------- fixed height I am setting on the container that is wrapped around the ListView widget
                        child: ListView.builder(    // <---------------- ListView widget
                          itemCount: 20,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Text('Heyyyy!');
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    : SizedBox()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

### Problem

In the above code, as I have pointed using arrows, **I am wrapping a `ListView` widget in a `Container` and assigning a fixed height to that `Container` since `ListView` widgets has an infinite height by default.**
The problem with this approach is, since that height I am providing to the container is a **fixed height**, the layout breaks on devices with small viewport heights, while it works fine with devices that has a large viewport height.
**So what I am trying to figure out is, how can I set a height to that `Container` that works on all devices without breaking the layout? (I am trying to make that height as maximum as possible without making the app break on smaller devices.)**

*(While researching about this, I came across [this stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368753/is-there-a-bounded-widget-that-can-constrain-listview-builder-in-a-column) and according to that link, I tried wrapping the `ListView` widget with a `Flexible` widget and set the `shrinkWrap` property of the `ListView` widget to `true`. This did not work and it caused my `ListView` widget and the other widget to gain as much space as possible between them and pushed my `ListView` widget to the bottom of the screen.)*

Comment: Since the `ListView` is a `Column` child, why don't you just wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded` widget? Wouldn't that do what you want ?

Comment: @esentis Your solution worked fine perfectly. One thing I would like to clarify from your answer is you mentioned `Since the ListView is a Column child`. Here I do not understand how `ListView` being a Column child becomes related to us wrapping it with an `Exapanded` widget? What does the `ListView` being a Column child has to do with it? (Thanks in advance)

Comment: It doesn't has to do with `ListView` specifically, in general as per documentation `Expanded` is a widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the your listview.builder in expanded then problem resolved

```
 Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 20,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text('Heyyyy!');
                  },
                ),
              ),
```